# Magento 2 - product passed to helper parameter is NULL

Tags: magento2, helper, magento2.3.4

I created this helper method:

**app\code\Company\Base\Helper\Product.php**

```
public function test($product = null)
{
    if (!empty($product)) { exit("TRUE, product is not empty!"); } else { return false; }
}
```

And injected it into a block, so I can use it there:

**THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="test" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Base\Helper\Product::test" />
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then I call my helper in **THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
<?php echo $block->getTest($_product); ?>
```

This is the template for the category view btw.

But I never get to see "TRUE, product is not empty!".

The same code works great in other locations e.g. on the block **product.info.media.image** with template
**Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml**

Answer (score 1):

You have done wrong. You should use view model https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html.

**I suggest that you have to use view model here instead of helper.**

- Create view model class at
  `app/code/Company/Base/ViewModel/Product.php`

  and implement `test($product = null)` method at there.

  **like**

```
    <?php

    namespace Company\Base\ViewModel;

    class Product implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
    {
        public function test($product = null)
        {
            if (!empty($product) || ($product != null)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false; 
             }
        }
    }
```

**phtml code look like:**

```
<?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
<?php $viewModel = $block->getViewModel(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
<?php echo $viewModel->getTest($_product); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) what is the advantage over my method? Why should we prefer your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work is because it is not intended to work like this. It is not a helper like in magento 1.

You can use the helper to get data, but you cannot add dynamic parameters into it from the template.

So I had to use `xsi:type="object"` instead:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">         
    <arguments>
        <argument name="company_helper" xsi:type="object">Company\Base\Helper\Product</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

I also had to implement `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface` in my helper class btw.

```
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface{
    ...
```

Then I used it like this:

```
$_helper = $block->getCompanyHelper();
$isProductNew = $_helper->isProductNew($_product);
```